# CAPWAP encryption

Tags: ieee-802.11, access-point, wlc, capwap

I'm new to wireless networking and I have a question that might be dumb.

Regular 802.11 uses AES/TKIP encryption. CAPWAP uses DTLS encryption, but CAPWAP is also 802.11 spec.
Can you please explain how this works? Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

CAPWAP is an application-layer protocol for wireless management. It's got its own DTLS encryption (in what you may call a sublayer).

Usually, CAPWAP runs over the wired network between the wireless controller and the WAPs. If you run it over a (probably separate) 802.11 link, the encapsulating frames are  additionally WPA2/3-encrypted on the data link layer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So it's like double encryption then when it comes to wireless.